# вывод многомерного массива в html по 4 товара в строку через js

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, bootstrap, flexbox

```
Как правильно вывести 4 товара в строку, затем еще ниже 4 по средством js? из предыдущего задания есть код таблицы 

https://jsfiddle.net/novikov433/yhdr1nvk/

нужно сделать все тоже самое, но по аналогии с уроком https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeVQwPBsZJY

https://jsfiddle.net/novikov433/9bekpna7/1/ 

то есть, понять как через бутсрап, флексбокс указать в дом свойствах что только у первых 4 элементов ширина = 25%, все остальные на строку ниже .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так например

```js
let data = [
 {
  name: {
   ru:'МТЗ',
   ua: 'МТЗ',
  },
  model: '82.1',
  country: {
   ru:'Беларусь',
   ua: 'Білорусь',
  },
  price: '1.11',
 },
 {
  name: {
   ru:'МТЗ',
   ua: 'МТЗ',
  },
  model: '892',
  country: {
   ru:'Беларусь',
   ua: 'Білорусь',
  },
  price: '1.21',
 },
 {
  name: {
   ru:'МТЗ',
   ua: 'МТЗ',
  },
  model: '920',
  country: {
   ru:'Беларусь',
   ua: 'Білорусь',
  },
  price: '1.31',
 },
 {
  name: {
   ru:'МТЗ',
   ua: 'МТЗ',
  },
  model: '92П',
  country: {
   ru:'Беларусь',
   ua: 'Білорусь',
  },
  price: '1.22',
 }
];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let templ = `<div class="col-3">
        <div class="grid__count">`+data[i]['name']['ru']+`</div>
        <a class="grid__link" href="">`+data[i]['model']+`</a>
        <div class="grid__name">`+data[i]['country']['ru']+`</div>
        <div class="grid__name">`+data[i]['price']+`</div>
    </div>`;

    $('#rezult').append(templ);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="rezult"></div>
```